# Extracting list of numbers from plain text file

Tags: batch-file

I have text file containing series of numbers following similar pattern:

```
<Lorepsum ipsum lores aus Lorep NUM="100" aus Lore>

<Lorepsum ipsum lores aus Lorpsum NUM="101" Lorepsum>

<Lorepsum ipsum lores aus Lorp77dsum NUM="102" ipsum lores aus>

<Lorepsum ipsum lores aus Lopsum NUM="103" lores aus>
```

Is it possible to write a windows batch script to extract the numbers from the file and put it into a new file?

o/p file should contain

```
101
102
103
104
```

Comment: What's the question? What do yopu want out of the file? The text (as your subject suggests)? or the numbers as the body of your question suggests. Can you give some example output that matches your example input?

Comment: Thanks Paul.I need to extract the numbers and write it into a new file.

Comment: Output file should contain "100","102","103"

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but it's not very pretty. The obvious candidate for this would b regular expressions which you only have for matching (and then only very limited) in batch files. If you'd use PowerShell then it'd just be

```
Get-Content foo.txt | ForEach-Object {
    [Regex]::Match($_,  'NUM="(\d+)"').Groups[1].Value
}
```

But sadly, in a batch file this is a little more complicated.

You can, however, use `for /f` to parse the file and then examine the tokens. There is no easy way to parse a line token by token, though. And tokenizing stops after 31 tokens (if I remember correctly). In any case, the following does work:

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%f in (foo.txt) do call :parse "%%f"
goto :eof

:parse
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set i=0
:parseImpl
set /a i+=1
(
  for /f "tokens=%i% delims= " %%l in (%1) do (
    rem Jump out if no more tokens are there
    if "%%l"=="" goto :eof
    rem Remember the token
    set T=%%l
    if "!T:~0,4!"=="NUM=" (
      set N=!T:~4!
      rem add redirection here if needed
      echo !N:"=!
    )
  )
) || goto :eof
rem This above will cause the loop to stop once no more tokens are there.
rem The for loop will return a non-zero exit code then.
goto parseImpl
```

It's not too pretty, but fairly straightforward. Since when reading a file I can use each line only once I delegate the work to a subroutine which goes over the line as often as necessary. For this the variable `i` is used which keeps track of the current token number. Then another `for` loop is employed which extracts the requested token from the string. If the token starts with `NUM=` then it is assumed to be the number you want. It is cleaned up and printed.

If you want them directly into a file, then change the respective line to

```
>out.txt echo !N:"=!
```

The code can also be found [in my SVN](http://svn.lando.us/joey/Public/SO/4367989).

Comment: Downvoter: Care to share the reason why? Did you even try the code?

Answer (score -1):

This should get you started:

```
@echo off
set cnt=0
set max=9
:enter_loop

if %cnt% GTR %max% goto end_loop
echo NUM="%cnt%" >> output.txt
set /a cnt="cnt+1"
goto enter_loop

:end_loop

pause
```

Comment: Thanks Falcon, but NUM="some_number" - only this patterns repeat in file. We can't depend on other text values.

Comment: See my edit. Please accept the answer if you liked it and vote it up. It writes the numbers from cnt to max in a file called output.txt

Comment: I need to read the text file and extract the numbers from it and write it into a new file.

Comment: What you're doing here is something entirely different. The OP doesn't want a file just with a few numbers. They need to match the numbers in another file, too.